# "... similar to what ..."

Tags: that, what

*"A high school, a private hospital and several apartment blocks are among the buildings identified with combustible cladding similar to what fuelled the Grenfell Tower fire."*

I read this sentence and it seemed to me that there was something not right about it. I don't know why but the use of "what" seemed wrong to me. I think a better sentence would read as follows.

*"A high school, a private hospital and several apartment blocks are among the buildings identified with combustible cladding similar to that which fuelled the Grenfell Tower fire."*

I'm interested to know, am I correct and if so why ?

Comment: Both versions are fine. I find *to that which* to be both slightly more formal and less natural sounding.

Answer (score -1):

I think the original version is possible as a more general reference to another material as 'a fuel'. 'What' fuelled the Grenfell Tower fire wasn't necessarily a '*similar cladding*' as it appears in case of using 'which'. It could be a different kind of material (e. g. a penetrating chemical), *similar in its danger* in the situation of fire.

> That combustible cladding was similar to what [= the improper kind of
>   material which] fuelled the Grenfell Tower fire.